# List of alternative stacktracing libraries for clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm looking for stacktrace libraries besides https://github.com/mmcgrana/clj-stacktrace and the default `clojure.stacktrace` implementation. Googling `stacktrace library clojure` does not yield any results. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: What is your requirement for an alternative?

Comment: I remember seeing a couple of libraries but now I can't find them. So I thought I would ask on SO

Comment: Maybe you were looking for `write-exception` in this: https://github.com/AvisoNovate/pretty ?

Comment: that is what I'm looking for! if you can write it up as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it

Comment: What should I write: "With no doubt you can mean only one thing: `write-exception` in this: github.com/AvisoNovate/pretty" Honestly it was just a guess. Most likely the downvotes come from people who would have liked a more specific question to be given a chance to write a good answer themselves. I can't really call my guesswork a quality answer but am certainly glad If I could help you.

Comment: Hahaha. Thanks @igrapenthin. I'm not too bothered about the down votes. I would rather loose some points than spend ages looking for the answer. Please write up your comment before the question gets closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for a better visual representation of exceptions, use `write-exception` in https://github.com/AvisoNovate/pretty

Unfortunately I could not yet figure out how to integrate such nice exceptions into my emacs/nrepl workflow (if I use the nrepl middleware, my emacs show quite ugly exceptions).

Comment: I've added my answer below

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help. The injections technique as well as the nrepl-middleware method gives me exceptions full of ^[37 literals. I am running Emacs on fedora 19.

Comment: Hmmm... It works for me but I'm using a mac...

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the `write-exception` method for `pretty` in nrepl/emacs the following should be added to profiles.clj via :injections.

```
{:user {:plugins []
         :dependencies [[io.aviso/pretty "0.1.8"]]
         :injections [(require 'io.aviso.repl 
                               'clojure.repl 
                               'clojure.main)
                      (alter-var-root #'clojure.main/repl-caught
                        (constantly @#'io.aviso.repl/pretty-pst))
                      (alter-var-root #'clojure.repl/pst
                        (constantly @#'io.aviso.repl/pretty-pst))]}}
```

There is another method proposed [here](https://github.com/AvisoNovate/pretty):

```
 :repl-options {
    :nrepl-middleware [io.aviso.nrepl/pretty-middleware]
 }
```

but i prefer the good old fashion way